# Print Elements of Row and column wise sorted matrix in sorted order

Tags: sorting, math, matrix

I am trying to print the below matrix in sorted order, but can't seem to think about any optimal solution. Can you please help?

```
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
4 7 8 9
5 6 9 10
```

Comment: If the matrix is sorted (whatever that means) it would be a different matrix. You'd better give more detail, and tag with a language.

Comment: What does "sorted" mean to you? Individual elements, rows, columns?

Comment: what are the things you have tried?

Comment: I want output like 1 2 2 3 4 4 4 5 5 6 8 9 9 10

Comment: It's row and column wise sorted matrix, i.e., particular row is sorted and so is particular column

Answer (score 2):

The following is an example of "sorted" - but you really need to tell us what "sorted" means to you:

```
1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 10
```

Here is code that will do this for you (using inefficient "bubble sort", which works fine on small arrays like this):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  int a[4][4] = {{ 1, 2, 3, 4},\
               { 2, 3, 4, 5},\
               { 4, 7, 8, 9},\
               { 5, 6, 9, 10}};
  int ii, jj;
  int *b, *p;
  b = malloc(sizeof(a));
  p = b; // copy pointer
  // copy 2d into linear array:
  for(ii = 0; ii< 4; ii++) {
    for(jj = 0; jj < 4; jj++) {
      *(p++) = a[ii][jj];
    }
  }
  // now do bubble sort:
  for(ii = 0; ii < 15; ii++) {
    for(jj = ii+1; jj < 16; jj++) {
      if(b[ii] > b[jj]) {
        int temp = b[ii];
        b[ii] = b[jj];
        b[jj] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
  // print result:
  for(ii = 0; ii < 15; ii++) {
    printf("%d, ", b[ii]);
  }
  printf("%d\n", b[15]);
}
```

Output:

```
1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 10
```

Comment: Yes that's the exact output I want

Comment: What help do you need? Converting 2D array into 1D array? Sorting 1D array? What does "optimal solution" mean for you? Is the array of variable size?

Comment: how are you using the fact that each row and column is sorted?

Comment: @Yash - I am not using that "fact". The question was unclear and there were no parameters given on the likely properties of the input matrix (or even a definition of "sorted" for the output...).

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use extra memory, then put this into an integer array and then use selection sort to print the respective nos.

Comment: You also need to tell the language used for this to have any context

Comment: I am trying to do in C